# New class add in existing dll and update it to source file code

Tags: c#, .net

I created a DLL dynamically using Microsoft.Csharp.CSharpCodeProvider and using System.CodeDom.Compiler namespaces. In this case, I have collection of class files with source code and using CSharpCodeProvider.CompileAssemblyFromFile(parameters,ClassFiles) method we compiled all class files and created as a single DLL (ex. ClientProx.dll).

I just copied that DLL (ex. ClientProx.dll) to another project. Now, I have a created new class with methods and how to add this new created class to the existing DLL (ex. ClientProx.dll) with old classes.

And after added the new class in that DLL (ex. ClientProx.dll), which should update in appropriate file as new class.

How can we do this at run time ? Is it possible add new class in existing DLL and update it to proper file location ?